# java.util.List<T> What does t stand for?

Tags: java, list, collections

Very simple question. I've been looking at JSpot documentation. 
http://jspot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html
What does T stand for? 
When it says it wants a list of type T I don't understand what T is?

Comment: Google java generics...

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of the Java language. Generics were added more than ten years ago so there is plenty of documentation and tutorials on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T is a Generic data type, i.e a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types
....take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. It doesn't explain what a "generic type" is for example.

Comment: when saying "take a look at this", it can help if you add something the this refers to

Comment: True but it answers my question in a timely manner. I wasn't sure if it what it stood for. Thank you for your help all.